# Why are there two different versions of my list in my code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am parsing a file in to memory, editing it, removing multiple entries, newlines, etc, then writing it to a new file.

For some reason, though, the line `mystatement = parsedoc[i]==parsedoc[j]` always returns false. It should check the next 20 available lines (without reaching outside the list) and if they match, it should remove it. However, when I do `print parsedoc[i],parsedoc[j]`, `parsedoc[j]` still has the new line at the end, which should have removed in a previous line, and which also does not show up in `parsedoc[i]`. I can rearrange my code to avoid this, but why is it happening?

Code:

```
#print "What file would you like to open?" #comment this and the next line back in
filename = "97_03_10.log" #raw_input("? ")

f = open(filename,'r')
filelines = f.readlines()
filedata = [len(filelines)]
parsedoc = []

del f

for line in filelines:
   parsedoc.append(line.split("\t")[1:])

#del filelines

for i in range(20):#len(parsedoc)-1): #this is where the magic happens
   if (not parsedoc[i]):
      print True
      continue

   parsedoc[i][1] = parsedoc[i][1].replace("\n","")
   if (parsedoc[i][1]==""):#remove empty entries
      parsedoc[i] = []
      continue

   for j in range(i+1,i+(20 if (20+i<len(parsedoc)) else (len(parsedoc)-i-1))):
      mystatement = parsedoc[i]==parsedoc[j]
      print parsedoc[i],parsedoc[j]
      if mystatement:
         parsedoc[j] = []

#for line in parsedoc:
#   print line

parsedoc = filter(None,parsedoc)

filedata.append(len(parsedoc))

print "Originally",
print filedata[0],
print "lines."
print "Currently",
print filedata[1],
print "lines."

for line in parsedoc[:20]:
   print line
```

Output: Just a heads up, these are native search results. There are swear words, and the usual suspects that you'd get if you took everyone's search results and compiled them.

http://pastebin.com/KBMudX7f

First 40 many lines of my input file, for testing: Again, there are swear words, and other undesirable words. NSFW.

http://pastebin.com/AgxnBMtF

Answer (score 3):

You're removing the newline characters inside the loop  on the `i`th elements, and since `j` starts at `i+1`, when you compare the elements at indices `i` and `j`, one will be stripped, and one won't.

Changing your initialization of `parsedoc` to:

```
for line in filelines:
    parsedoc.append(line.strip().split("\t")[1:])
```

Will strip the newline from every line, before the `for i` / `for j` loops.

This also means you can get rid of `parsedoc[i][1] = parsedoc[i][1].replace("\n","")`

With this edit, you'll get:

```
Originally 49 lines.
Currently 44 lines.
```

---

**Edit**:  You can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) package to re-write your code as:

```
import csv
#print "What file would you like to open?" #comment this and the next line back in
filename = "97_03_10.log" #raw_input("? ")

filedata = []

# Read file into parsedoc
parsedoc = []
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        parts = line[1:]
        if parts[1] == '': continue
        parsedoc.append(parts)
        print parts
filedata.append(len(parsedoc))

# "Filter" parsedoc
for i,pdi in enumerate(parsedoc[0:20]):             # Slice notation won't raise an
    for j,pdj in enumerate(parsedoc[i+1:i+1+20]):   #   IndexError for OOB
        #print pdi,pdj
        if pdi == pdj:
            print("Element match found at i=%d, j=%d: %s" % (i,i+1+j, pdi))
            del parsedoc[j]
filedata.append(len(parsedoc))

print("Originally %d lines." % filedata[0])
print("Currently %d lines." % filedata[1])
```

Comment: Ok, what if you have 50k to 1m+ elements? Am I going to face performance problems?

Comment: Both your code and my edit read the entire file into memory (in the `parsedoc` list).  My edit is a bit more efficient, but if that is too big you could read a block of lines from `reader`, operate on them, read another block, etc.  Try it out.

Comment: It looks like striping the whitespace that early also breaks the "for" loop later on, so I modified it to check for a single element as well. I'm not sure how your suggestion fits in with what I'm trying to do, but it looks very well written.